# How to copy information from one sheet to another in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I work in a call centre where we have to leave notes after every call, to keep track of calls and follow-ups I'm trying to figure out the code to have it copy and pasted automatically to the next cell that is blank in Sheet2

I have tried adding the Importsheet / Activesheet paste but it just replaces the cells in the next sheet over. I can't figure out how to include Isblank in the code for it to paste under

```
Sub CopyData()
    Sheets(“ImportSheet”).Select
    Range(“A1:A5”).Copy
    Sheets(“DataTable”).Select
    Range(“A1”).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

This is the example I've used from a website.

It just replaces the cells in the next sheet.

Answer (score 0):

To find the next empty row in the DataTable sheet, you can use

```
dim lRow as long
lRow = Sheets("DataTable").cells(Rows.Count,"A").end(xlup).row + 1
```

Then you can paste into that row. You don't need to select the cells in order to copy and paste.

```
Sub CopyData()
    dim lRow as long
    lRow = Sheets("DataTable").cells(Rows.Count,"A").end(xlup).row + 1
    Sheets("ImportSheet").Range("A1:A5").Copy Sheets("DataTable").Range("A" & lRow).Paste
End Sub
```

Note that the code you posted has "fancy quotes". These won't work in VBA. Web sites often convert straight quotes to curly quotes. You need to replace them with straight double quotes before running the code.